(How to) Request that the specialized topic tag [live-photos] not be a synonym for the much broader general tag [photos]
Problem Summarize
I would like to explore and contribute on the focused tag of [live-photos] without getting tossed into the largest broader [photos] tag.
The [live-photos] tag …/questions/tagged/live-photos currently aliases to [live-photos] or [photos].
What is the process for requesting that [live-photos] not be a synonym which aliases to [photos]?
Details & Research Comment
The "live photos" topic currently has around 200 to 300 Q&A posts. While the [photos] tag is approximately an order of magnitude larger with over 2,000 entries.
It seems reasonable that Apple Live Photos would have it's own topic tag as much as topic tags like [google-photos], [photo-booth] or [photo-stream]:

What Was Tried
I had expected the [live-photos] tag to exist and be useful… where the alias jump to [live-photos] or [photos] which failed to narrow results. The string-based search of "live photos" did yield 280 Q&A posts

"What is the process for requesting that [live-photos] not be a synonym which aliases to [photos]?" you're correct by posting it on the meta, gather the community consensus, and then wait for a mod to remove the synonym.

Agreed, live-photos does not meet the criteria of ‘common, alternate spellings or phrasings’ of photos to be a synonym.
I don't intend to act unilaterally before the community has had a chance to vote on this properly, but this sort of change is easily reversed should the community disagree.
I have therefore removed the synonym and live-photos is now standalone.
